# Web API OAuth token endpoint 404

Tags: asp.net, api, oauth, owin

I have a Web Forms solution, and I'm trying to add in a self-hosted API project to power interaction from mobile requests (using http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/01/token-based-authentication-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/ as my refernce point).  However, when configuring my OAuth's "TokenEndpointPath" I'm getting a 404 response - only in my production environment which is hosted at discountasp.net.  Locally, it works perfect.

In my Website project, I have a global.asax which has an empty Application_Start() method.  In my API project, I have this in my Startup.cs:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyDomain.API.Startup))]

namespace MyDomain.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions OAuthBearerOptions { get; private set; }

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            //use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();

            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(),
                RefreshTokenProvider = new SimpleRefreshTokenProvider()
            };

            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

And this as my API project's App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs:

```
namespace MyDomain.API
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
            jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what other info you might need, but does anyone know why I'd be getting a 404 when trying to POST to http://mydomain/token?  To be clear, my Website project is the one returning the 404 response (I'm getting the HTML output of my custom 404 page... not a server message in JSON format or anything like that).

Comment: (I ommitted the "using" declarations in the code snippets for brevity)

Comment: Just wondering can you hit the http://mydomain/token without the OWIN stuff?

Comment: Not totally sure what you mean... what are you proposing I remove in order to test that?

Comment: I am suggesting you make sure that this is not a simple 404 and is related to the authlayer.

Comment: did you had any progress with that ?